# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wellness'

Tags: python, django, attributes, keyword

While the title says the issue is 'wellness' truth is it picks a random item on the form and says thats the issue.

**surveys.views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from surveys.forms import SurveyForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

@login_required
def storeBloodData(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST)

        if(form.is_valid()):
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            bd = SurveyForm (user=cd['user'],
                            timestamp=cd['timestamp'],
                            glucose=cd['glucose'],
                            wellness=cd['wellness'],
                            weight=cd['weight'],
                            foodGroups=cd['foodGroups'],
                            )
            bd.save()
            print("Saved weather record...")
        else:
            return render(request,
                          'bdata_form.html',{'form':form})

    print("should be calling status...")
    return render(request, 'welcome.html',{'term':"Saved data to     d/base..."})
```

**surveys.forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from surveys.models import Survey
from django.conf import settings

FOOD_CHOICE = {
        ('D','Diary'),
        ('F','Fruit'),
        ('G','Grains'),
        ('M','Meats'),
        ('V','Vegetables'),
        ('S','Sweets'),
    }

class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = (  'glucose',
                    'weight', 'foodGroups',
                    'wellness', 'user',
                    'timestamp'
                )
```

**surveys.models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.models import User




# Create your models here.

FOOD_CHOICE = {
        ('D','Diary'),
        ('F','Fruit'),
        ('G','Grains'),
        ('M','Meats'),
        ('V','Vegetables'),
        ('S','Sweets'),
    }


NUM_CHOICE = {
        ('1','1'),
        ('2','2'),
        ('3','3'),
        ('4','4'),
        ('5','5'),
        ('6','6'),
        ('7','7'),
        ('8','8'),
        ('9','9'),
        ('10','10'),
}

class Survey(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Survey.user')
    glucose = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('date published', default='1990-08-26')
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    foodGroups = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    wellness = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=NUM_CHOICE, default="1")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

**More info**
So it loads the form correctly (and I was able to add a survey from the admin side) but whenever I try to add it from the site end, it throws the error.

Comment: Post template code and full stack trace

Comment: Hi Selcuk,

Thanks for your edits, I'm still learning the ropes here! Daniel Roseman below has pointed out the error (below).

thank you for your advise however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate a SurveyForm, rather than a Survey, inside your is_valid block.

But actually you shouldn't be trying to do either, and you don't need to set all those fields from cleaned_data: the whole point of using a ModelForm is that you can just do `form.save()` and it creates and saves a model instance for you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Well I feel like the fool. That has indeed worked, thank you!

when you say form save, do you mean the following:

if(form.is_valid()):
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            
            cd.save()
            print("Saved record...")

Sorry, I just want to learn more about what you said. :)
And that way at least in the future I could at least help out on such a question should it arise again!

Comment: No, there's no need to access cleaned_data at all. Just `if form.is_valid(): form.save()`. (And note that if conditions don't need parentheses in Python.)